# workflow - if then (email notif not working)

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQOO4.jpg) Click to see image

I'm currently doing a workflow with email notification such as below:

1. If status is pending and NOT modified by request owner, then email the request owner
2. if status is pending and is modified by request owner, then email the lead (field: email address)

my problem is that for # 2, email goes to the request owner instead of the lead (field: email address)

Here's the workflow:

if current item:status equals pending
and current item: Modified by not equals current item:request owner
        email current item: request owner

if current item:status equals pending
and current item: Modified by equals current item:request owner
        email current item: email address

Comment: Can you post a screen capture of that part of your workflow?

Comment: stackexchange doesnt allow me to attach photos but ive written the workflow above

Comment: Hi, I've included the image above. thanks!